# IIS 7 slow to do anything

Tags: iis-7, iis

I installed IIS fresh yesterday on my dev box and at the time it was working perfectly.
I rebooted this morning and now I can't debug my websites in Visual Studio because the web server doesn't respond.
I've tried viewing sites in inetmgr too, but it never expands the Sites item in the tree view.

I've installed the following components:

```
Internet Information Services
    Web Management Tools
        IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility
    IIS Management Console
    IIS Management Scripts and Tools
    World Wide Web Services
        Application Development Features
            .NET Extensibility
            ASP
            ASP.NET
            CGI
            ISAPI Extensions
            ISAPI Filters
            Server Side Includes
        Common HTTP Features
            Default Document
            Directory Browsing
            HTTP Errors
            HTTP Redirection
            Static Content
            WebDAV Publishing ............... Not sure I need this one
        Performance Features
            Dynamic Content Compression
        Security
            Request Filtering
```

I'm at a loss as to what the problem could be. In all the time it's taken me to write this post, IIS has been trying to expand the Sites list in the management console. It hasn't changed at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: get rid of webdav, i have had that brick my iis before to where it couldn't serve requests. check the event log for error messages too

Answer (score 1):

Some things has changed. Try to find out what happens with the sysinternals tool procmon[1].

[1] http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

This helps me often to understand what happens in processes and/or system.

Comment: Based on what I saw there, it seemed likely to me that my AV is killing IIS for some reason, so I've added IIS to my AV's exceptions list and we'll see how that goes

Comment: seems it was my AV blocking IIS somehow. Haven't had any problems since yesterday when I created an exception in my AV for it. Wouldn't have been able to find out if I hadn't seen Avast mentioned on the IIS process in the sysinternals so thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK so it wasn't just that IIS was slow. IIS wasn't working at all and I found out why.
The 1st answer by `f4m8` has a link to an app that let me examine my processes to see what was going on.

When I found inetinfo.exe running, I saw something mentioning my anti-virus software which made me wonder if the AV was bullying IIS.

I added IIS to my AV's exception list so that it wouldn't be monitored and this has solved the problem.

Comment: If this is the solution, you can accept your own answer as such.

Comment: Unfortunately, no joy. Even with IIS added to my AV's exceptions list, the problem persists.